# Decorating a JTextField with an image and hint

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, decorator, jtextfield

I'm trying to create some nicer looking JTextFields with an image and a hint. To do this I made a decorator that overrides the paintComponent method. The reason I used a decorator is that I wanted to apply it to other types of JTextField such as JPasswordField.

Here is what I've made so far;

[image]

The problem as seen in the form on the left is that, even though I have used a JPasswordField the paintComponent seems to ignore what I assume is the passwords paintComponent which presumably does the password masking symbols.

So the question is, how can I avoid duplicating the code for JTextFields and JPasswordFields but still have the different functionality such as password masking.

This is the decorator code;

```
public class JTextFieldHint extends JTextField implements FocusListener{
private JTextField jtf;
private Icon icon;
private String hint;
private Insets dummyInsets;

public JTextFieldHint(JTextField jtf, String icon, String hint){
    this.jtf = jtf;
    setIcon(createImageIcon("icons/"+icon+".png",icon));
    this.hint = hint;

    Border border = UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border");
    JTextField dummy = new JTextField();
    this.dummyInsets = border.getBorderInsets(dummy);

    addFocusListener(this);
}

public void setIcon(Icon newIcon){
    this.icon = newIcon;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int textX = 2;

        if(this.icon!=null){
            int iconWidth = icon.getIconWidth();
            int iconHeight = icon.getIconHeight();
            int x = dummyInsets.left + 5;
            textX = x+iconWidth+2;
            int y = (this.getHeight() - iconHeight)/2;
            icon.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
        }

        setMargin(new Insets(2, textX, 2, 2));

        if ( this.getText().equals("")) {
            int width = this.getWidth();
            int height = this.getHeight();
            Font prev = g.getFont();
            Font italic = prev.deriveFont(Font.ITALIC);
            Color prevColor = g.getColor();
            g.setFont(italic);
            g.setColor(UIManager.getColor("textInactiveText"));
            int h = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
            int textBottom = (height - h) / 2 + h - 4;
            int x = this.getInsets().left;
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            RenderingHints hints = g2d.getRenderingHints();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.drawString(hint, x, textBottom);
            g2d.setRenderingHints(hints);
            g.setFont(prev);
            g.setColor(prevColor);
        }

}

protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
    this.repaint();
}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
    this.repaint();
}


}
```

And this is where I create the fields;

```
JTextField usernameField = new JTextFieldHint(new JTextField(),"user_green","Username");
JTextField passwordField = new JTextFieldHint(new JPasswordField(),"bullet_key","Password");
```

Hopefully i've not went completely off in the wrong direction here!

Thanks!

EDIT : Again the more I look at it, it is obvious that calling super.paintComponent(g) is going to call the JTextFields paintcomponent, but I can't see how to solve this without duplicating the code.

Answer (score 8):

[Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) works with a JPasswordField.

One difference is that the displayed icon disappears when text is entered. If you want the icon to be permanent then I suggest you create a custom "IconBorder* class to paint an Icon rather then do custom painting in the paintComponent() method.

You approach will not work unless you duplicate the code for both JTextField and JPasswordField.

Edit:

Actually you don't need to create a custom IconBorder. The MatteBorder supports the painting of an Icon in a Border.

Comment: You can create a CompoundBorder. Use the original border as the outer Border and then use a MatteBorder with an Icon as the inner Border

Answer (score 5):

In order to paint an icon inside a text field you need to add some insets.
You don't want to hard-code insets in your component but just add a little bit of space for the icon, letting clients and subclasses to set their own.

[image]

In the figure above I painted original insets in green and additional insets in red. First thing you want to extend JTextField. We keep track of two things: the original insets (the green ones) `mBorder`, and the icon.

```
public class IconTextField extends JTextField {
    private Border mBorder;
    private Icon mIcon;

    // ...
}
```

Then you need to override [`setBorder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder(javax.swing.border.Border)) method.

```
@Override
public void setBorder(Border border) {
    mBorder = border;

    if (mIcon == null) {
        super.setBorder(border);
    } else {
        Border margin = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, mIcon.getIconWidth() + ICON_SPACING, 0, 0);
        Border compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, margin);
        super.setBorder(compound);
    }
}
```

Here, if we have an icon (the field `mIcon` is not `null`), we add our additional insets using a compound border. Then, you should also override the [`paintComponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) method.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paintComponent(graphics);

    if (mIcon != null) {
        Insets iconInsets = mBorder.getBorderInsets(this);
        mIcon.paintIcon(this, graphics, iconInsets.left, iconInsets.top);
    }
}
```

Finally, you need a `setIcon()` method.

```
public void setIcon(Icon icon) {
    mIcon = icon;
    resetBorder();
}

private void resetBorder() {
    setBorder(mBorder);
}
```

What we are doing here is saving the icon and recalculating the borders.

If you want to do the same same thing with `JPasswordField`, the most elegant thing is probably to create a helper class with all the methods discussed above.

```
class IconTextComponentHelper {
    private static final int ICON_SPACING = 4;

    private Border mBorder;
    private Icon mIcon;
    private Border mOrigBorder;
    private JTextComponent mTextComponent;

    IconTextComponentHelper(JTextComponent component) {
        mTextComponent = component;
        mOrigBorder = component.getBorder();
        mBorder = mOrigBorder;
    }

    Border getBorder() {
        return mBorder;
    }

    void onPaintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (mIcon != null) {
            Insets iconInsets = mOrigBorder.getBorderInsets(mTextComponent);
            mIcon.paintIcon(mTextComponent, g, iconInsets.left, iconInsets.top);
        }
    }

    void onSetBorder(Border border) {
        mOrigBorder = border;

        if (mIcon == null) {
            mBorder = border;
        } else {
            Border margin = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, mIcon.getIconWidth() + ICON_SPACING, 0, 0);
            mBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, margin);
        }
    }

    void onSetIcon(Icon icon) {
        mIcon = icon;
        resetBorder();
    }

    private void resetBorder() {
        mTextComponent.setBorder(mOrigBorder);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public class IconTextField extends JTextField {
    private IconTextComponentHelper mHelper = new IconTextComponentHelper(this);

    public IconTextField() {
        super();
    }

    public IconTextField(int cols) {
        super(cols);
    }

    private IconTextComponentHelper getHelper() {
        if (mHelper == null)
            mHelper = new IconTextComponentHelper(this);

        return mHelper;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        getHelper().onPaintComponent(graphics);
    }

    public void setIcon(Icon icon) {
        getHelper().onSetIcon(icon);
    }

    public void setIconSpacing(int spacing) {
        getHelper().onSetIconSpacing(spacing);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBorder(Border border) {
        getHelper().onSetBorder(border);
        super.setBorder(getHelper().getBorder());
    }
}
```